# Axios return data can't be fetch

Tags: reactjs, axios

**Axios not worked:**

```
axios
  .get("http://localhost:8080/user", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + props.token,
    },
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("user: " + result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

**when I use fetch(), this work properly**

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/user", {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + props.token,
  },
})
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((resData) => {
    console.log("u ", resData);
  });
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: yeah. can u explain more about the error

Comment: I solve the value right now. the problem was in print the value.

console.log("user: " + result);
when i use "+" then i got undefined value.

console.log("user: ", result);
but when i use "," then i got all data. 

can you explain what is difference between "+" and ","